# Parse.comにandroid端末からmp4の映像をアップロードする方法

Tags: android, parse.com

[Parse.com](https://parse.com/) に Android 端末から MP4 の映像をアップロードする方法がわからないです。

```
File file=new File(path);
    try {
        byte[] data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);//Convert any file, image or video into byte array
        ParseFile Pfile = new ParseFile("sample.mp4", data);
        Pfile.saveInBackground();
        ParseObject jobApplication = new ParseObject("JobApplication");
        jobApplication.put("applicantName", "Joe Smith");
        jobApplication.put("applicantResumeFile", Pfile);
        jobApplication.saveInBackground();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: アップロードする方法が分からない、だけではこちらも分かりませんので、and_gao さんがどういった点で躓いているのか教えて頂けませんか？ (例えばエラーが出るなど) ちなみに ParseFile は 10MB 以上のファイルは保管できません。[Parse - Android - ファイル](https://parse.com/docs/jp/android_guide/#files)

Answer (score 1):

Shironeさんの言う通り、10MB以上のファイルを転送する事は出来ません。例外処理をくんでおきましょう。
あと、

```
byte[] data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);\
```

の部分ですが、私はこのサイトのByte変換を使わせていただいています。
http://propg.ee-mall.info/%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0/java/java-%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E8%AA%AD%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E9%85%8D%E5%88%97%E3%81%AB%E5%85%A5%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B/

```
private byte[] readFileToByte(String filePath) throws Exception {
    byte[] b = new byte[1];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while (fis.read(b) > 0) {
        baos.write(b);
    }
    baos.close();
    fis.close();
    b = baos.toByteArray();

    return b;
}
```

これをソースに書いて、readFileToByte(path);としています。